# SCSS styling not being applied correctly to Angular App run through NGINX on AWS EC2

Tags: angular, nginx, amazon-ec2, sass

I'm currently trying to run my angular app on AWS EC2, and I've succeeded in adding it to NGINX and accessing the application through the public IP. However, whenever I actually access the page, the styling is wrong. A lot of the component styling appears to be there; however, the height is shrunk from the entire view to simply a very small thin line. How can I get the styling to appear correctly? It works whenever I run ng serve --open on my local machine.

Also, I'm using SCSS on the project if that makes a difference.

[image: Only thin line displayed on the public IP for EC2 instance]

Comment: Can you post the link to the site if it's public? need to find out who is setting height. You can use Chrome dev tools and check which class has set the height and then debug why that class is behaving like this.

Comment: http://3.128.251.137/ @NikhilWalvekar

Comment: I was able to see the full page, not the image which is shown above. Which browser are you trying?

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar huh, that's really weird. I'm on Safari but it works on Chrome